# Problem with getting unique output in script

Tags: scripting

I have a file containing list of URLs (one entry in one line).

After processing it to extract the host- (server-)names
with the script below (which works correctly),
the host names that appeared multiple times in the input
were appearing multiple times in the displayed output. 
I want each name to appear only once. 
I tried `uniq` and `sort -u`, but they didn't help. 
Below is the code I had used to extract the hosts:

```
function extract_parts {
    if [ -f "wget-list" ]; then
        while read a; do
            a=${a:8}

            host=$(echo -e "$a"  | awk -F '/' '{print $1}' | sort -u)
          # host=$(echo -e "$a"  | awk -F '/' '{print $1}' | uniq -iu)

            echo -e ${host}

        done <<< $(cat ./wget-list)
    fi
}
```

where the `wget-list` contains (as a truncated example):

```
https://downloads.sourceforge.net/tcl/tcl8.6.12-html.tar.gz
https://downloads.sourceforge.net/tcl/tcl8.6.12-src.tar.gz
https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/source/J/Jinja2/Jinja2-3.1.2.tar.gz
https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/source/M/MarkupSafe/MarkupSafe-2.1.1.tar.gz
https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/autoconf/autoconf-2.71.tar.xz
https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/automake/automake-1.16.5.tar.xz
```

Result after the script
(only the hosts, without the `https://` and path parts):

```
downloads.sourceforge.net
downloads.sourceforge.net
files.pythonhosted.org
files.pythonhosted.org
ftp.gnu.org
ftp.gnu.org
```

Desired output (the above, but with no duplicates):

```
downloads.sourceforge.net
files.pythonhosted.org
ftp.gnu.org
```

Comment: (1) Your `a=${a:8}` statement strips the first eight characters off `$a`.  This will give undesired results if you ever get a URL beginning with `http://` (or `ftp://`, etc.) instead of `https://`.  (2) You should always quote all shell variable references (e.g., `"$host"`) unless you have a good reason not to, and you’re *sure* you know what you’re doing.  (3) Why are you using the `-e` option of `echo`? P.S. `printf` is better than `echo`. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … (4) As Gilles Quenot showed in [his answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/728849/80216), but did not mention: there’s no need to say `<<< $(cat ./wget-list)` — `< ./wget-list` is better. (5) See [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/80216)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> while read a; do
> ```

You're reading one line...

> ```
> host=$(echo -e "$a"  | awk -F '/' '{print $1}' | sort -u)
> ```

and printing that in a pipeline which you then sort and take the unique lines out of. That'll give you one unique line.

Then you're doing the same for the next line, totally separately.

Instead, just pass the whole file through a pipeline, e.g.

```
$ < ./wget-list sed -e 's,^https://,,'  | awk -F/ '{print $1}' |sort -u
downloads.sourceforge.net
files.pythonhosted.org
ftp.gnu.org
```

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out. I tryed to to do it without regex because I haven't fully learned it

Comment: UPDATE: Ok, thanks. It had helped. Now I need only to find a method with would allow cause that when spliting with the `awk`, would self set the `$..`, where ".." is the number of the separated part

Comment: @Mcgiwer: Some general advice: 1. As a rule of thumb, don't `while read` if you can avoid it. 2. If you must use `while read`, keep the interior of the loop as simple as possible. 3. Remember that `while` is *one big command*, and so you can pipe into/out of it. 4. You don't need to use `awk` for simple field splitting, as `cut` can also do that and is more straightforward to use (but awk is probably more useful to learn in the long run).

Comment: @ilkkachu I have a question related to your code. In the orginal code, whe n I had wsed thw I had used the `while`, I had cut out the" https" with the bash code `${variable: 8}` wouldn't be possible to use is somehow in your code ?

Comment: @Mcgiwer, well. That's the shell's substring operator, so you can't use exactly that unless you do the text processing in the shell. But that's not a really good idea since tools like sed and awk are just better at that (and faster). Consider that your original loop launches three separate processes for each input line (the pipeline in the command substitution), and that's just unnecessary overhead.

Comment: You could use the equivalent function in awk: `substr(string, start, end)`, though. E.g. `< ./wget-list awk -F/ '{$0 = substr($0, 9); print $1}' |sort -u`. (`$0` is the current line, and assigning back to it has AWK redo the field splitting to `$1`, `$2`, ... Also the string indexing starts from 1, and not 0 like in the shell, so to drop the first 8 characters, we need to take the string starting from character 9 (and not 8))

Comment: you could also use just `< ./wget-list awk -F/ '{ print $3}' |sort -u`, and then we didn't even need to care if the protocol is `https:` or `http:` or `ftp:`, as it'd just take the part between the second and third slashes.

Comment: @lkkachu I had asked because in my code did text processing (using the mentioned bash replacement) to remove the "https://" part and simplicize future extractions (aspecially in case if in the file would appear a longer entry)

Answer (score 4):

If you have GNU `grep`, the default on Linux, you could simplify with :

```
extract_parts(){
    grep -oP 'https?://\K[^/]+' "$1" | sort -u
}
```

### Output

```
$ extract_parts wget-list

downloads.sourceforge.net
files.pythonhosted.org
ftp.gnu.org
```

### correction of your script

Your text manipulation is wrong. You get only `https:` and you try to sort only unique lines (that makes no sense).

A working copy:

```
if [[ -f wget-list ]]; then
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        host=$(awk -F '/' '{print $3}' <<< "$line")
        echo "$host"
    done < ./wget-list | sort -u
fi
```

The sort should *englob* the whole `while` loop to work as you want.

Comment: While this works, it doesn't answer the question (why `uniq` wasn't working for OP).

Comment: Yes, added 'correction of your script' paragraph

Comment: @Gilles Quenot Thanks and I have a question rełated to it because I think it could become optimized for better performance. In the `while` loop, you can cut the "https://" out before processing the "host=(...)" line. This way, the `$3` will become `$1`